# launch java applet with jnlp but with unspecified width and height

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start

I have an applet and would like to launch it via jnlp. Currently it launches, but the problem is in the width and height. If I launch the applet manually (java -jar applet.jar), I don't specify a width and height. The applet decides itself what size it should be depending on some other dynamic conditions. But when launched via a jnlp file (javaws applet.jnlp), I have to specify a size. Is it possible to launch an applet via jnlp and let the applet decide its own size? If I simply leave out the width and height from the jnlp file, I get an error saying that width and height are required. But only the applet knows what the width and height should be. Also, I don't want to modify the source code for the applet. Is this possible and how?

Comment: *"..Also, I don't want to modify the source code for the applet. Is this possible and how?"*  If 'no alter' also means 'no extend' then, no.

Comment: How much of the applet context does the applet use?  If 'none' it might be easier to add it to a frame.

Comment: AT was correct. I would have to modify the source, but don't want to mess with that. So I found another applet to serve my purpose which seems to work fine without specifying width or height.